# Is there a way to efficiently get three layer aggrigations result in elasticsearch, where each layer is conditioned by above one

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, composite

I am trying to get composite aggregation for certain feilds which are present in each document. These documents are stored in elastic.
Format of each document is a json with below mentioned keys.
**{"id","name","topic","bucket","key"}**

Now I want to get result in below format:
**From documents, how much each topic count is, how much each bucket count is for each topic and how much key count is for each bucket.**
Now I had thought of using three layer aggrigation query, but is real slow for api's.
Could anyone suggest some better options.

*Currently, Index size is 141.7mb, number of documents are in range of  8000-10000, topic, bucket and key can be around 1000-2000 each.
Each documents will have some 100-200 each of topic, bucket and keys and can be different for each document.*

Current I am using below three level aggrigation query.

```html
GET index/doc/_search
{
            "aggs":{
              "topic_aggs": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "topic.keyword",
                  "size":10000
                },
                "aggs" : {
                  "bucket_aggs" : {
                    "terms": {
                      "field": "bucket.keyword",
                      "size":10000
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                      "key_aggs": {
                        "terms": {
                          "field": "key.keyword",
                          "size":10000
                        },
                      }}
                  }}
              }}}
```

And this is used in an API, so running it takes around 3-4s. This is where I want to make it efficient to return results quick.

Comment: Can you provide numbers of (documents, topics, buckets, keys)?

Comment: @cidermole I have made edits, please check and do reply.